# What does => without right operand mean in scala?

Tags: scala

I know what => operator means. E.g Int => Boolean, but in Trait definition, I dont see any right operand. What does "self: Repr =>"  mean? I can only partially fill it. self is a var? function that takes an input Repr and returns what?

```
trait LinearSeqLike[+A, +Repr <: LinearSeqLike[A, Repr]] extends SeqLike[A, Repr] {
  self: Repr =>

  override protected[this] def thisCollection: LinearSeq[A] = this.asInstanceOf[LinearSeq[A]]
  override protected[this] def toCollection(repr: Repr): LinearSeq[A] = repr.asInstanceOf[LinearSeq[A]]

  def seq: LinearSeq[A]

  override def hashCode()= scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3.seqHash(seq) // TODO - can we get faster via "linearSeqHash" ?

  override /*IterableLike*/
  def iterator: Iterator[A] = new AbstractIterator[A] {
    var these = self
    def hasNext: Boolean = !these.isEmpty
    def next(): A =
      if (hasNext) {
        val result = these.head; these = these.tail; result
      } else Iterator.empty.next()

    override def toList: List[A] = {
      /* Have to clear `these` so the iterator is exhausted like
       * it would be without the optimization.
       *
       * Calling "newBuilder.result()" in toList method
       * prevents original seq from garbage collection,
       * so we use these.take(0) here.
       *
       * Check SI-8924 for details
       */
      val xs = these.toList
      these = these.take(0)
      xs
    }
  }
```

Comment: The closest I see in that link talks about => in a type with no left parameter. But this is without right parameter.

Moreover there is no mention about this type of statement without a "var" or "val" prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ravi that is the Scala self type.. it can be used for dependency injection. So as of now it is not pointing to any real type, but using code can pass in a concrete type that complies to that trait.
See [this](https://coderwall.com/p/t_rapw/cake-pattern-in-scala-self-type-annotations-explicitly-typed-self-references-explained).